# jQuery to get screen height change table to height

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I want my table or div to cover 100 percent of the users screen but height"100%" does not work.  I am trying to use jQuery to get the screen size, which I can do but how do I put it in the table height code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>For The Holy Church</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/BG.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #181818;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#Main {
    background-image: url(images/HolyBG.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%"  border="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Main">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table width="100%" height="100px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/TopBG.jpg">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <table width="100%" height="350px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/VaticanBG.jpg">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td><img src="images/banner/01.jpg" alt="" width="933" height="350" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <pre><script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").text(screen.height);

});
</script>
<br />
      </pre>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**My issue is that the table only goes as far as the content and not the screen height.**

Comment: If your div is not directly a child of the body, it will get 100% of it's parent, not of the body (and thus the screen).

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code, but you might also need to ensure that `html` and `body` also have `height:100%` as your div is within those.

Answer (score 0):

```
body: {height:100%;width:100%;}

div: {height:100%;width:100%;}

table: {height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each parent element of the table should have it's height set to 100%.

A height in percentage sets the element's height to 100% of its *parent* only. It will not go larger than that.

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For the table above to fill the screen, each of its parent: div,body and html tags must have its height set to 100%.